# Formula Field Is Undefined In Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, formula-field, aura-attribute, lightning-inputfield

I am trying to populate some lightning: inputs in an aura component with a few values.  In the example below, {!v.enrollmentRecord.Comments__c} works fine but  {!v.enrollmentRecord.OPEID__c} is undefined.  The OPEID__c field is a formula text field which simply grabs a number value to the Enrollment records related Account.  When I try "component.get("v.enrollmentRecord.OPEID__c");" in the controller it also does not return anything but the field is populated in the page layout in the org.  What can I do to properly grab this field?

Enrollments.cmp

```
<aura:attribute name="enrollmentRecord" type="Enrollemnt__c" />

<div class="slds-col_padded slds-size_3-of-3">
    <lightning:input type="text" label="OPEID" value={!v.enrollmentRecord.OPEID__c}" disabled="true" variant="label-inline"/>
</div>
<div class="slds-col_padded slds-size_3-of-3">
    <lightning:input type="text" label="Comments" value="{!v.enrollmentRecord.Comments__c}" required="true" variant="label-inline"/> 
</div>
```

EnrollmentsController.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        
        var lastYear = new Date().getFullYear() - 1;

        component.set("v.currentYear",lastYear.toString() + ' - ' + currentYear.toString());
        //get Layout, build Reporting Period combobox
        helper.getInstitution(component, event, helper).then(institution => {
            component.set("v.institution", institution);
        }).catch(error => {
            helper.toast(
                "There was an error.",
                error.message,
                "error",
                "sticky",
                5000
            );
        }).then(() => {
            helper.getReportingPeriodOptions(component, event, helper).then(rptPeriods => {
                component.set("v.reportingPeriods", rptPeriods);
                if(rptPeriods.length > 0) {
                    component.set("v.selectedReportingPeriod", rptPeriods[0].value);
                }

            }).catch(error => {
                helper.toast(
                    "There was an error.",
                    error.message,
                    "error",
                    "sticky",
                    5000
                );
            });
        });
    },
    handleReportingPeriodChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.whichPage",1);
        //need to show the previous buttons
        helper.showHide(component, "previousTop", true);
        helper.showHide(component, "previousBottom", true);
        helper.showHide(component, "spinner", true);
        //clear totals
        component.set("v.saraCount", 0);
        component.set("v.nonSARACount", 0);
        helper.getEnrollmentLayout(component, event, helper).then(layout => {
            component.set("v.layoutInfo", layout);
            if(!layout.hasLayout) {
                component.set("v.whichPage",2);
                
                //need to hide the previous buttons
                helper.showHide(component, "previousTop", false);
                helper.showHide(component, "previousBottom", false);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            helper.toast(
                "There was an error.",
                error.message,
                "error",
                "sticky",
                5000
            );          
        }).then(() => {
            helper.getEnrollment(component, event, helper).then(enrollment => {
                component.set("v.enrollmentRecord", enrollment);
                helper.calculateTotals(component, event, helper, true, "");
                console.log('enrollmentRecord set...');
                helper.showHide(component, "spinner", false);
            }).catch(error => {
                helper.toast(
                    "There was an error.",
                    error.message,
                    "error",
                    "sticky",
                    5000
                );  
                helper.showHide(component, "spinner", false);
            });         
        });
    },
    onRecordSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
        helper.showHide(component, "spinner", true);
        var requiredState = component.get("v.institution").SPA_Account__r.BillingState + "__c";
        var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
        var isSubmit = component.get("v.isSubmit");
        var requiredMessage = 'The following fields are Required to Submit, please provide a value: ';
        var missingRequired = false;
        if(isSubmit) {
            eventFields["Data_Collected_Date__c"] = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
            eventFields["Is_Completed__c"] = isSubmit;

            if($A.util.isEmpty(eventFields["Name__c"])) {
                missingRequired = true;
                requiredMessage += "Name, ";
            }
            if($A.util.isEmpty(eventFields["Email__c"])) {
                missingRequired = true;
                requiredMessage += "Email Address, ";
            }
            if($A.util.isEmpty(eventFields["Out_Of_State_Branch_Activity__c"]) || eventFields["Out_Of_State_Branch_Activity__c"] == "— Select an option —") {
                missingRequired = true;
                requiredMessage += "Out Of State Branch Activity, ";
            }
            if(eventFields["Agreement_Acknowledgement__c"] != true) {
                missingRequired = true;
                requiredMessage += "Agreement, "
            }   
        }
        if(!missingRequired) {
            var layout = component.get("v.layoutInfo");
            //zero out the blanks
            for (let state of layout.saraStates) {
                if(state != requiredState) {
                    var stateCount = eventFields[state];
                    if($A.util.isEmpty(stateCount) || stateCount == undefined) {
                        eventFields[state] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (let state of layout.nonSaraStates) {           
                if(state != requiredState) {
                    var stateCount = eventFields[state];
                    if($A.util.isEmpty(stateCount) || stateCount == undefined) {
                        eventFields[state] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            component.find("enrollmentEdit").submit(eventFields);
        }
        else {
            requiredMessage = requiredMessage.substr(0,requiredMessage.length-2);
            helper.toast(
                "Enrollment Error",
                requiredMessage,
                "error",
                "sticky",
                5000
            );
            helper.showHide(component, "spinner", false);
        }
    },
    onSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.showHide(component, "spinner", true);
        helper.saveEnrollment(component, event, helper);
        var opeidId = component.get("v.enrollmentRecord.Id");
        console.log(opeidId);
        var opeidVal = component.get("v.enrollmentRecord.OPEID__c");
        console.log(opeidVal);
        console.log("Testing here:");
        console.log(component.get("v.recordId"));

    },
    onSaveSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.showHide(component, "spinner", true);
        component.set("v.isSubmit", true);
        var layout = component.get("v.layoutInfo");
        confirm("You are about to submit your " + layout.title + ". Please check to insure your results are correct, as you will not be able to edit this report once its submitted.");
        event.preventDefault();
        helper.showHide(component, "spinner", true);
        var enroll = component.get("v.enrollmentRecord");
       
        
        var requiredMessage = 'The following fields are Required to Submit, please provide a value: ';
        var missingRequired = false;
        var ackValue = component.find("ack");
         
        if(!ackValue.get("v.checked")) {
            missingRequired = true;
            requiredMessage += "Agreement, "
         }  
         if($A.util.isEmpty(enroll.Name__c)) {
            missingRequired = true;
            requiredMessage += "Name, "
         }  
         if($A.util.isEmpty(enroll.Email__c)) {
            missingRequired = true;
            requiredMessage += "Email, "
         }
         if(component.find("branchActivity").get("v.value") == '— Select an option —') {
            missingRequired = true;
            requiredMessage += "Out Of State Branch Activity, "
         }
        helper.calculateTotals(component, event, helper,false, "sara");
        helper.calculateTotals(component, event, helper,false, "non");
        
        if( component.get("v.nonSARACount") == 0 &&  component.get("v.saraCount") == 0 && !component.find("noEnroll").get("v.checked")){
            missingRequired = true;
            requiredMessage += "This institution has zero Distance Education Enrollments to report , "
        }
        
        if(!missingRequired) {
            helper.saveEnrollment(component, event, helper);
        }
        else {
            requiredMessage = requiredMessage.substr(0,requiredMessage.length-2);
            helper.toast(
                "Enrollment Error",
                requiredMessage,
                "error",
                "sticky",
                5000
            );
            helper.showHide(component, "spinner", false);
        }
        
    },
    onPrevious : function(component, event, helper) {
        var whichPage = component.get("v.whichPage");
        var isDirty = component.get("v.isDirty");
        var keepGoing = true;
        if(whichPage == 2 && (isDirty)) {
            keepGoing = confirm("You have unsaved changes on this page. You will lose these changes if you continue. Do you want to continue?");
        }
        if(keepGoing) {
            component.set("v.isDirty",false);
            component.set("v.whichPage",1);
        }
    },
    onNext : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isRendered",false);
        component.set("v.whichPage",2);
        component.find("branchActivity").set("v.value", component.get("v.enrollmentRecord").Out_Of_State_Branch_Activity__c);       
    },
    onSARAChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isDirty",true);
        helper.calculateTotals(component, event, helper, false, "sara");
    },
    onNonSARAChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isDirty",true);
        helper.calculateTotals(component, event, helper, false, "non");
    },
    showHideDetails : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.showHideDetails(component, helper);
    }
})
```

EnrollmentsHelper.js

```
({
    getEnrollmentLayout : function(component, event, helper) {
        return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
            var action = component.get("c.getLayout");
            var reportingPeriod = component.get("v.selectedReportingPeriod");
            var periods = component.get("v.reportingPeriods");
            for (let period of periods) {
                if(period.value === reportingPeriod) {
                    component.set("v.selectedReportingPeriodLabel", period.label);
                    action.setParams({
                        "reportingPeriod" : period.label
                    });
                    break;
                }
            }

            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();

                if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                    resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    console.log(errors[0].message);
                    reject(errors);
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }));
    },
    getInstitution : function(component, event, helper) {
        return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
            var institutionId = component.get("v.institutionId");
            var action = component.get("c.getInstitution");
            action.setParams({
                "institutionId" : institutionId
            });

            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();

                if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                    resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    console.log(errors[0].message);
                    reject(errors);
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }));
    },
    getReportingPeriodOptions : function(component, event, helper){
        return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
            var institutionId = component.get("v.institutionId");
            var action = component.get("c.getEnrollmentPeriodsForInstitution");
            action.setParams({
                "institutionId" : institutionId
            });

            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();

                if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                    resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    console.log(errors[0].message);
                    reject(errors);
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }));
    }, 
    getEnrollment : function(component, event, helper) {
        return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
            var action = component.get("c.getEnrollment");
            var reportingPeriod = component.get("v.selectedReportingPeriod");
            action.setParams({
                "enrollmentId" : reportingPeriod
            });

            action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                var state = response.getState();

                if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                    resolve(response.getReturnValue());
                } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    console.log(errors[0].message);
                    reject(errors);
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }));
    },
    showToast : function(params) {
        return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams(params);
            toastEvent.fire();
            resolve();
        }));
    },
    toast: function (title, msg, type, mode, duration) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        if (toastEvent) {
            toastEvent.setParams({
                'title': title,
                'message': msg,
                'type': type,
                'mode': mode,
                'duration': duration || 0
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        } else {
            var vfToast = $A.get('e.c:vfToast');
            vfToast.setParams({
                'title': title,
                'message': msg,
                'type': type,
                'mode': mode,
                'duration': duration || 0
            });
            vfToast.fire();
        }
    },
    showHide : function(component, elementName, isShow) {
        var el = component.find(elementName);
        if(isShow) {
            console.log('showing ', elementName);
            $A.util.removeClass(el, "slds-hide");
        }
        else {
            console.log('hiding ', elementName);
            $A.util.addClass(el, "slds-hide");
        }
    },
    saveEnrollment : function(component, event, helper) {
      return new Promise($A.getCallback((resolve, reject) => {
                     var action = component.get("c.saveEnrollment");
                    action.setParams({
                        "isSubmit" : component.get("v.isSubmit"),
                        "enrollment" : component.get("v.enrollmentRecord"),
                        "branchActivity" : component.find("branchActivity").get("v.value")
                    });
        
                    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
                        var state = response.getState();
        
                        if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                           helper.onRecordSuccess(component, event, helper);
                        } else if(state === "ERROR"){
                            var errors = response.getError();
                            console.log(errors[0].message);
                            reject(errors);
                        }
                    });
                    $A.enqueueAction(action);
                }));       
    },    
    showHideDetails : function(component, helper) {
        var enrollment = component.get("v.enrollmentRecord");
        helper.showHide(component, "saraStateSec", !enrollment.No_Enrollments_To_Report__c);
        helper.showHide(component, "nonSaraStateSec", !enrollment.No_Enrollments_To_Report__c);
    },
    calculateTotals : function(component, event, helper, isInitial, type) {
        var layout = component.get("v.layoutInfo");
        var saraStateCount = layout.saraStates.length;
        var nonSaraStateCount = layout.nonSaraStates.length;
        if(isInitial) {
            var enrollment = component.get("v.enrollmentRecord");
            var saraCount = component.get("v.saraCount");
            console.log("before saraCount ", saraCount);
            var nonSARACount = component.get("v.nonSARACount");
            console.log("before nonSARACount ", nonSARACount);
            for (let state of layout.saraStates) {          
                var stateCount = enrollment[state];
                if(!$A.util.isEmpty(stateCount) && stateCount != undefined) {
                    saraCount += enrollment[state];
                }
            }
            for (let state of layout.nonSaraStates) {           
                var stateCount = enrollment[state];
                if(!$A.util.isEmpty(stateCount) && stateCount != undefined) {
                    nonSARACount += enrollment[state];
                }
            }
            component.set("v.saraCount", saraCount);
            console.log("saraCount ", saraCount);
            component.set("v.nonSARACount", nonSARACount);
            console.log("nonSARACount ", nonSARACount);
            //component.set("v.enrollmentRecord.OPEID__c", 222222);
            
            //component.find("branchActivity").get("v.value")
        }
        else {
            if(type == "sara") {
                var saraCount = 0;
                var stateCountFields = component.find("saraStates");
                //calc sara
                for (let state of stateCountFields) {
                    var stateCount = state.get("v.value");
                    if(!$A.util.isEmpty(stateCount) && stateCount != undefined) {
                        if (parseInt(stateCount) < 0) {
                            state.set("v.value",parseInt(stateCount)*-1);
                            saraCount += (parseInt(stateCount)*-1);
                        }
                        else if(parseInt(stateCount) >= 0) {
                            saraCount += parseInt(stateCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
                component.set("v.saraCount", saraCount/saraStateCount);
            }
            if(type == "non") {
                var nonSARACount = 0;
                var stateCountFields = component.find("nonSARAStates");
                //calc sara
                for (let state of stateCountFields) {
                    var stateCount = state.get("v.value");
                    if(!$A.util.isEmpty(stateCount) && stateCount != undefined) {
                        if (parseInt(stateCount) < 0) {
                            state.set("v.value",parseInt(stateCount)*-1);
                            nonSARACount += (parseInt(stateCount)*-1);
                        }
                        else if(parseInt(stateCount) >= 0) {
                            nonSARACount += parseInt(stateCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
                component.set("v.nonSARACount", nonSARACount/nonSaraStateCount);
            }
        }
    },
    onRecordSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getEnrollment(component, event, helper).then(enrollment => {
            var isSubmit = component.get("v.isSubmit");
            component.set("v.enrollmentRecord", enrollment);
            component.set("v.isDirty",false);
            helper.toast(
                "Enrollment",
                "Your entries have been Saved " + (isSubmit ? "and Submitted successfully!" : " successfully, however, your entries have not been Submitted yet."),
                "success",
                "sticky",
                5000
            );

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("save error: ",error.message);
            helper.toast(
                "There was an error.",
                "An Error occurred and your entries were not saved. Please try saving again, so you don’t lose any work.",
                "error",
                "sticky",
                5000
            );
        }).finally(() => {
            helper.showHide(component, "spinner", false);
        });
    },
    onRecordError : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.showHide(component, "spinner", false);
    },
})
```

UPDATE to include full controller code

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. We'd also need to see how you're loading the record (JS and Apex, if any). Formula fields do work correctly, so the presumption is that you've done something incorrectly. You can [edit] your question to include more code or other details.

Comment: Please add more details such as controller code and explain how and when that controller code is being called to fetch the data and when is `component.get("v.enrollmentRecord.OPEID__c");` getting called.

Comment: @NagendraSingh I updated the post to include the controller code.  Thanks a ton for your help

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a stupid mistake and selected every field except OPEID__c in the SOQL query in the apex controller. Thanks anyway for the willingness to help!